# Respective form should display only when i check box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

iam trying to achieve this exact functionalty: http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/  BUT inside using my PHP, right now its displaying 2 checkboxes and 2 forms, BUT what I need is: those  2 forms shouldnt be visible unless I check any box..

so, please check whats wrong in below code...

```
function eshop_extras_checkout($echo){


    $echo .= '

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 

    <script>

    $(".formGroup").hide();
    $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        }
    });
    ​
</script>';

    $echo .= '<fieldset class="eshop eshop_extra">' . "\n";


    $echo .= ' <form id="chooseForm">
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
    </form>

    <form id="form1" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 1</h2>
        <label>Name</label><input type="text"> <br>
        <label>Address</label><input type="text">
    </form>

    <form id="form2" class="formGroup">
        <h2>FORM 2</h2>
        <label>Username</label><input type="text"> <br>
    </form>';


    $echo .= '<legend>Articles Order Form</legend>' . "\n";



    return $echo;
}
```

waiitng for your replies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your script executes before the elements are present in the DOM. See:

```
//when this line executes:
$(".formGroup").hide(); //the .formGroup is not present in the DOM yet
//in other words, the jQuery object is empty and calling .hide() does nothing

//the same happens to this handler binding:
$("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", ...
```

Your fiddle's JS is set to use the `onDomReady` wrapper, that's why it works properly there.

You can put the script below the form's HTML, and/or simply wrap the script contents inside a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    $(".formGroup").hide();
    $('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        }   
    });
});
```

---

One of jQuery's best practices to always wrap your code in a [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), that is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //code here
});
```

or the much shorter shorthand:

```
$(function() {
    //code here
});
```

Both have the same effect, they prevent the code from executing until the DOM is ready.

Another JavaScript best practice is to put the JS code in the footer of the page (right before the `</body>`), this way scripts loading won't block the page rendering and when the DOM parser reaches the scripts, your DOM will be already ready for them.

Both best practices above are combinable. Nevertheless, simply using the DOM ready handler will solve the issue, as well as moving the scripts to below the form HTML will also suffice.

---

Your framework is already loading another copy of jQuery in `noConflict` mode, that means you can't use the `$` alias in the global scope. To remedy that, you can use this special DOM ready syntax, which will alias jQuery back to `$` inside its scope:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".formGroup").hide();
    $("#chooseForm input:checkbox").on("change", function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
        }
        else {
            $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

More info on that from the DOM ready handler docs - Aliasing the jQuery Namespace:

> When using another JavaScript library, we may wish to call
>   `$.noConflict()` to avoid namespace difficulties. When this function is
>   called, the `$` shortcut is no longer available, forcing us to write
>   `jQuery` each time we would normally write `$`. However, the handler
>   passed to the `.ready()` method can take an argument, which is passed
>   the global `jQuery` object. This means we can rename the object within
>   the context of our `.ready()` handler without affecting other code.

Comment: HI, As you said I wrapped DOM and tried, BUT still forms form1 and form2 displaying... BUT i want them to display only when I check or uncheck boxes...

Comment: Check the console for errors. It must work, if it doesn't is because you either have invalid syntax somewhere or a conflict somewhere.

Comment: And here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/YyGwj/) with all the code echoed from your question's PHP (with added DOM ready handler), works fine.

Comment: HI,  I have exactly used your code in my php file.. please check this ;ink: your-guru.com/articless/  , first add to cart and then go upto checkout, you will find 'Articles Order Form' , just below you will find 2 forms.. 

iam really sorrry if iam troubling you, BUT i am really not getting and Iam a newbie to this coding...

Comment: @Harris well if you look in the console: `TypeError: $ is not a function` that's because your framework is already loading another copy of jQuery into noConflict mode. Gimme a minute while I make an update.

Comment: @Harris Check if you have any luck with the last piece of code that I just updated into my answer. `=]`

Comment: woww! now 2 forms hided, but another new prob now... when I check box forms not appearing... whats the prob..?

Comment: Try removing the jQuery 1.8.2 include, remove the `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` line as you already have another jQuery version included. Check if it helps. `=]`

Comment: Another problem is that your Form1 Form2 inputs are not inside the `#chooseForm`

Comment: Yeah, now put a div or a form or something with `id="chooseForm"` wrapping those 2 checkboxes, then it will work.

Comment: Or just copypaste it from your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/), your checkboxes aren't inside the `chooseForm` in the live page. `=]`

Comment: I aleady have a form wrapped the checkboxes: here it is:


<form id="chooseForm">
         <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
     </form>


what u want me to change exactly?

Comment: This is the exact php line:   

 $echo .= ' <form id="chooseForm">
         <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form1"> Form1<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="form1" value="form2"> Form2<br>
     </form>

Comment: Oh my bad, I assumed it wasn't there because it doesn't appear in the DOM inspector. It is actually in the source, but the parser ignores it because you can't have a form inside of a form. Change the start and end tag of that form to `<div id="chooseForm">` and `</div>` instead of `</form>`, it should work then.

Comment: The next problem you come to is probably that the 2 forms will also bug because you can't have a form inside a form. Change those to `div`s and they should work too. `=]`

Comment: Brotheeeeeeeeeeeeeerrr , Thanks a lotttttttt! U made it.. iam very happy now..  :) you have a gr8 skill and I appreciate you working for me, and Thnq vm for your precious time spending and solving this..


Thanks again!  Gud day and have  a gud luck in ur life! :)